# RxJava - Control one Observable by another one

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

**Updated**

I'm looking for a way to control the flow of one observable by another one. For example, let's have 2 **monotically increasing (important)** observables of integers:

```
source  : 1----2-2---2--3--3--4----4--5---6----8---9---10--------11------
control : -1----3----------------5-----------6-------9-----------12------
```

I need to produce a new observable, whose elements exactly match the source, but their timing is controlled by control observable in the following way: the source values should always be less or equal to control values. This means that only all source values, which are greater than recently published control should wait until they are "released" by control

```
source         : 1----2-2---2--3--3--4----4--5---6----8---9---10--------11------
control        : -1----3----------------5-----------6-------9-----------12------
expected result: -1----2-2--2--3--3-----4-4--5------6-------8-9---------10-11---
```

Please take a look at the following code example:

```
private static <T, C> Observable<T> combine(Observable<T> source, Observable<C> control, BiFunction<T, C, Boolean> predicate) {
    // ???
}

@Test
public void testControl() throws InterruptedException {
    Subject<Integer> control = PublishSubject.create();
    Observable<Integer> source = Observable.fromArray(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11);
    Observable<Integer> combined = combine(source, control, (s, c) -> s <= c);
    control.subscribe(val -> System.out.println("Control: " + val));
    combined.observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(val -> System.out.println("Value: " + val));

    control.onNext(3); // should release 1,2,2,2,3,3
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    control.onNext(6); // should release 4,4,5,6
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    control.onNext(11); // should release 8,10,11
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some code?

Comment: @Devstr, I've added the code and tried to make the question more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't find any elegant solution, I ended up with implementing it by my own. I will be happy if I someone can suggest more elegant solution (in this case I will unaccept this answer and will accept the better one). Following is my solution:

```
private static <T, C> Observable<T> combine(Observable<T> source, Observable<C> control, BiFunction<T, C, Boolean> predicate) {
    return Observable.create(emitter -> {
        Queue<T> buffer = new ArrayDeque<>();
        AtomicReference<C> lastControl = new AtomicReference<>();
        CompletableSubject sourceCompletable = CompletableSubject.create();
        CompletableSubject controlCompletable = CompletableSubject.create();
        Disposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable(
                control.subscribe(
                        val -> {
                            lastControl.set(val);
                            synchronized (buffer) {
                                while (!buffer.isEmpty() && predicate.apply(buffer.peek(), val)) {
                                    emitter.onNext(buffer.poll());
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        emitter::onError,
                        controlCompletable::onComplete),
                source.subscribe(
                        val -> {
                            C lastControlVal = lastControl.get();
                            synchronized (buffer) {
                                if (lastControlVal != null && predicate.apply(val, lastControlVal)) {
                                    emitter.onNext(val);
                                } else {
                                    buffer.add(val);
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        emitter::onError,
                        sourceCompletable::onComplete),
                controlCompletable.andThen(sourceCompletable).subscribe(emitter::onComplete));
        emitter.setDisposable(disposable);
    });
}
```

Comment: Solution like this makes me question whether RxJava is the right tool for your problem..

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine [buffer](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#buffer-rx.Observable-) functionality (which will buffer the items for you) with [combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#combineLatest-rx.Observable-rx.Observable-rx.functions.Func2-) functionality (which will determine when the buffer can be released).

```
Observable<Integer> source;
Observable<Integer> control;

Observable<Integer> canRelease = Observable.combineLatest(source, control, (s, c) -> s < c ? s : null).filter(val -> val != null);

Observable<Integer> result = source.buffer(canRelease).flatMap(Observable::from);
```

The resulting Observable will buffer source items until there is a value in `canRelease`. `canRelease` will emit every time source Observable latest item becomes less than control Observable latest item;

Comment: Sorry, it seems like the question was not clear enough. I tried to make it more clear